# PHP sleep() function

Tags: php

When I am running following php script which uses sleep() method to execute code after some interval. When I am running the script it gives the outputs all at once when it completes the loop. I need that it display output after each execution of loop.

```
<?php
$count=0;
$n=10;

set_time_limit(2000);

while($count<$n)
{
    sleep(30);
    echo time();
    echo "Timer Run....".$count."<br>";
    $count++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 11):

Everytime you want PHP to send your output to the client you need to call

```
flush();
```

Since by default PHP will send all it's output at the end of the script.

More information on how PHP handles it's output: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php